# FTL Communication using Quantum Entanglement (A new Approach)

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

Ok i have a proposition:

Imagine there are two people 1 on earth and other in space.

They syncronised their clocks before they left earth and agreed that they will factor in time dilation and regularly update their clocks to account for the other.

Now they agree that in 10 years the first person to collapse the entanglement will be the guy in space and he can do that before the guy on earth every time as he has a clock that keeps track of the time on earth as mentioned above.

They also agree that if the spin is up then the guy in space will head to a certain planet if down then no.

Now after ten years the guy in space will first make his observation and decide to go or not based on the spin.

This info is communicated to the guy on earth as he necessarily opens it after the guy in space.

In this case the choice the guy makes in space,the information travels faster than light.

I observe no problems with this system.

Very interested in the counter points

**Edit**:it works classically as well.It was a dumb question.Thanks for indulging in it regardless

Comment: Please clean this up a bit.  You don't say, but it seems that they created an entangled pair before the left each other.  Also, I don't understand "every time" in the paragraph that starts "Now they agree ...".    What are they doing repeatedly?  And "... if the spin is up..."  what spin?    Can you clarify?

Comment: this works classical if they split up the kings on a chess set without looking at the color, until 10 years.

Comment: I meant that this setup is very dependent on the space guy reliably collapsing the state before the earth guy so by "every time" I meant it can be reproduced reliably.Regarding spin i meant electron spins as that's commonly used in topics related to Quantum Entanglement but I should have clarified.Also the agreement is a one of thing that they did before the space guy left earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no communication happening at a distance here: the communication happened beforehand, when they agreed how to interpret the results.

We can easily do this classically as well. I will write the same word, either "up" or "down", on two pieces of paper and seal them in envelopes. I will use a fair coin flip to decide what word to write. I then give one envelope to "Earth guy" and one envelope to "space guy". I ask them to open their envelopes 10 years from now, at the same time, and if they see "up" they will both know instantly that "space guy" is going to Planet X, and if they see "down" they know he won't. Neither knew before they opened the envelope.

There is nothing magical about this.

Comment: I like that most of the naive proposals with entanglement and things somehow ends up with time dilation.

Comment: Entanglement is not the same as classical correlation...

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to clarify it for me.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I agree. The "communication" protocol suggested didn't use any quantum features either. Hence why the same protocol can be implemented classically.